# Huffman encoding in Rust

Tags: reinventing-the-wheel, rust, compression

An implementation of Huffman encoding / decoding as a learning exercise. I'm still new to Rust, so any tips about making things more natural for the language are appreciated.

```
mod huff {

    use std::boxed::Box;
    use std::cmp::Ordering;
    use std::collections::BTreeMap;
    use std::collections::BinaryHeap;
    use std::fmt::Write;

    pub struct SymbolFreq {
        symbol: char,
        frequency: u32,
    }

    fn make_frequency_table(input: &String) -> Vec<SymbolFreq> {

        let mut freqs = BTreeMap::new();

        for c in input.chars() {
            *freqs.entry(c).or_insert(0) += 1;
        }

        let mut result = freqs.iter().map(|(k, v)| SymbolFreq{ symbol: *k, frequency: *v }).collect::<Vec<_>>();

        result.sort_by(|a, b| a.frequency.cmp(&b.frequency));

        result
    }

    pub struct Node {
        left : Option<Box<Node>>,
        right : Option<Box<Node>>,
        symbol_freq : SymbolFreq,
    }

    impl Node {
        fn is_leaf(&self) -> bool {
            self.left.is_none() && self.right.is_none()
        }
    }

    impl PartialEq for Node {
        fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
            self.symbol_freq.frequency.eq(&other.symbol_freq.frequency)
        }
    }

    impl Eq for Node { }

    impl PartialOrd for Node {
        fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
            other.symbol_freq.frequency.partial_cmp(&self.symbol_freq.frequency)
        }
    }

    impl Ord for Node {
        fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
            other.symbol_freq.frequency.cmp(&self.symbol_freq.frequency)
        }
    }

    fn make_heap_node(symbol_freq: SymbolFreq) -> Box<Node> {
        Box::new(Node{ left: None, right: None, symbol_freq: symbol_freq })
    }

    fn make_combined_heap_node(left: Box<Node>, right: Box<Node>) -> Box<Node> {

        let symbol_freq = SymbolFreq{ 
            symbol: 0 as char, 
            frequency: left.symbol_freq.frequency + right.symbol_freq.frequency
        };

        Box::new(Node{ left: Some(left), right: Some(right), symbol_freq: symbol_freq })
    }

    fn make_queue(input: Vec<SymbolFreq>) -> BinaryHeap<Box<Node>> {

        let mut freqs = BinaryHeap::with_capacity(input.len());

        for e in input {
            freqs.push(make_heap_node(e));
        }

        freqs
    }

    fn make_tree(mut input: BinaryHeap<Box<Node>>) -> Option<Box<Node>> {

        if input.is_empty() {
            return None;
        }

        let root;

        loop {

            assert!(!input.is_empty());

            let l = input.pop().unwrap();

            let r = match input.pop() {
                Some(x) => x,
                None => { root = l; break; },
            };

            let n = make_combined_heap_node(l, r);

            match input.is_empty() {
                true => { root = n; break; },
                false => input.push(n),
            }
        }

        assert!(input.is_empty());

        Some(root)
    }

    fn make_encoding_table(input: &Option<Box<Node>>, mut encoding: Vec<bool>, output: &mut BTreeMap<char, Vec<bool>>) {

        let n = match input.as_ref() {
            Some(x) => x,
            None => return,
        };

        if n.is_leaf() {

            if encoding.is_empty() { // root is leaf! -> add extra bit
                encoding.push(false);
            }

            assert!(output.insert(n.symbol_freq.symbol, encoding).is_none());
        }
        else {

            let mut l = encoding.clone();
            l.push(false);
            make_encoding_table(&n.left, l, output);

            let mut r = encoding;
            r.push(true);
            make_encoding_table(&n.right, r, output);
        }
    }

    fn make_encodings(input: &String) -> (Option<Box<Node>>, BTreeMap<char, Vec<bool>>) {

        let freqs = make_frequency_table(input);
        debug::print_frequencies(&freqs);

        let queue = make_queue(freqs);
        debug::print_queue(&queue);

        let root = make_tree(queue);
        debug::print_tree(&root);

        let mut encodings = BTreeMap::new();
        make_encoding_table(&root, Vec::new(), &mut encodings);

        (root, encodings)
    }

    fn do_encoding(input: &String, encodings: &BTreeMap<char, Vec<bool>>) -> Vec<bool> {

        let mut result = Vec::new();

        for c in input.chars() {
            result.extend(encodings.get(&c).unwrap());
        }

        result
    }

    fn do_decoding(input: &Vec<bool>, root: &Option<Box<Node>>) -> Result<String, &'static str> {

        let mut result = String::new();
        let mut i = 0usize;

        while i != input.len() {

            let mut next = root;

            loop {

                let node = match next.as_ref() {
                    Some(x) => x,
                    None => return Err("do_decoding() failed: reached null node in tree."),
                };

                if node.is_leaf() {
                    result.push(node.symbol_freq.symbol);
                    break;
                }

                if i == input.len() {
                    return Err("do_decoding() failed: reached end of input partway through decoding char.");
                }

                next = match input[i] {
                    false => &node.left,
                    true => &node.right,
                };

                i += 1;
            }

            if next == root { // root is leaf! -> always consume at least one bit!
                i += 1;
            }
        }

        Ok(result)
    }


    pub type Tree = Option<Box<Node>>;
    pub type EncodedData = Vec<bool>;

    pub fn encode(input: &String) -> (Tree, EncodedData) {

        let (tree, encodings) = make_encodings(input);
        debug::print_encodings(&encodings);

        let encoded_data = do_encoding(input, &encodings);
        debug::print_byte_comparison(input, &encoded_data);

        (tree, encoded_data)
    }

    pub fn decode(input: &EncodedData, tree: &Tree) -> Result<String, &'static str> {
         do_decoding(input, tree)
    }


    mod debug {

        use super::*;
        use std::collections::BTreeMap;
        use std::collections::BinaryHeap;
        use std::fmt::Write;

        pub fn print_frequencies(frequencies: &Vec<SymbolFreq>) {
            println!("frequencies:");
            for e in frequencies.iter() {
                println!("\t({}, {})", e.symbol, e.frequency);
            }
        }

        pub fn print_queue(queue: &BinaryHeap<Box<Node>>) {
            println!("queue:");
            for n in queue {
                println!("\t({}, {})", n.symbol_freq.symbol, n.symbol_freq.frequency);
            }
        }

        fn print_node(node: &Option<Box<Node>>, indent: u32) {
            let n = match node.as_ref() {
                Some(x) => x,
                None => return,
            };

            for _ in 0..indent {
                print!("\t");
            }
            println!("({}, {})", n.symbol_freq.symbol, n.symbol_freq.frequency);

            print_node(&n.left, indent + 1);
            print_node(&n.right, indent + 1);
        }

        pub fn print_tree(root: &Option<Box<Node>>) {
            println!("tree:");
            print_node(&root, 0);
        }

        fn encoding_to_string(encoding: &Vec<bool>) -> String {
            let mut s = String::with_capacity(encoding.len());
            for b in encoding {
                write!(&mut s, "{}", *b as u8).unwrap();
            }
            s
        }

        pub fn print_encodings(encodings: &BTreeMap<char, Vec<bool>>) {
            println!("encodings:");
            for (k, v) in encodings {
                print!("{}: {}\n", k, encoding_to_string(v));
            }
        }

        pub fn print_byte_comparison(unencoded: &String, encoded: &Vec<bool>) {
            print!("data: {}\n", encoding_to_string(&encoded));
            print!("original: {}bytes\nencoded: ~{}bytes\n", unencoded.len(), encoded.len() / 8);
        }

    } // debug

    #[cfg(test)]
    mod tests {

        use super::*;

        #[test]
        fn encode_decode_empty_input() {
            let input = "".to_string();
            let (t, d) = encode(&input);

            assert!(t.is_none());
            assert!(d.is_empty());

            let o = decode(&d, &t).unwrap();

            assert_eq!(o, input);
        }

        #[test]
        fn encode_decode_single_char_input() {
            let input = "aaaaaaa".to_string();
            let (t, d) = encode(&input);

            assert!(!t.is_none());
            assert!(!d.is_empty());

            let o = decode(&d, &t).unwrap();

            assert_eq!(o, input);
        }

        #[test]
        fn encode_decode_two_char_input() {
            let input = "abaabbaa".to_string();
            let (t, d) = encode(&input);

            assert!(!t.is_none());
            assert!(!d.is_empty());

            let o = decode(&d, &t).unwrap();

            assert_eq!(o, input);
        }

        #[test]
        fn encode_decode_three_char_input() {
            let input = "   abaa    bba a".to_string();
            let (t, d) = encode(&input);

            assert!(!t.is_none());
            assert!(!d.is_empty());

            let o = decode(&d, &t).unwrap();

            assert_eq!(o, input);
        }

        #[test]
        fn encode_decode_utf8_input() {
            let input = " αβ 忠犬ハチ公 hi".to_string();
            let (t, d) = encode(&input);

            assert!(!t.is_none());
            assert!(!d.is_empty());

            let o = decode(&d, &t).unwrap();

            assert_eq!(o, input);
        }

        #[test]
        fn decode_empty_encoded_data() {

            let input = " αβ 忠犬ハチ公 hi asdkfweiuryhfiusdf".to_string();
            let (t, d) = encode(&input);

            assert!(!t.is_none());
            assert!(!d.is_empty());

            let o = decode(&Vec::new(), &t).unwrap();

            assert!(o.is_empty());
        }

        #[test]
        #[should_panic(expected = "reached end of input")]
        fn decode_corrupt_encoded_data() {

            let input = " αβ 忠犬ハチ公 hi asdkfweiuryhfiusdf".to_string();
            let (t, mut d) = encode(&input);

            assert!(!t.is_none());
            assert!(!d.is_empty());

            d.pop();
            d.pop();

            let _ = decode(&d, &t).unwrap();
        }

        #[test]
        #[should_panic(expected = "reached null node")]
        fn decode_corrupt_tree() {

            let input = " αβ 忠犬ハチ公 hi asdkfweiuryhfiusdf".to_string();
            let (mut t, d) = encode(&input);

            assert!(!t.is_none());
            assert!(!d.is_empty());

            t.as_mut().unwrap().left = None;

            let _ = decode(&d, &t).unwrap();
        }

    } // tests

} // huff


#[cfg(not(test))]
fn main() {

    let input = "this is an example for huffman encoding";
    print!("input: {}\n", input);

    let (tree, data) = huff::encode(&input.to_string());

    let output = huff::decode(&data, &tree).unwrap();
    print!("output: {}\n", output);
}
```

Things I wonder about:

- It seems like a lot of trait implementations are required to put something in a `BinaryHeap`... is there a simpler way?
- The compiler claims `std::fmt::Write` is unused, but if I comment it out, it doesn't compile.
- The version of Rust I have installed is kinda old (`rustc 1.3.0 (9a92aaf19 2015-09-15)`) as I've been without internet. Are there things that could be improved with a more modern version?

Any other feedback is welcome.